# Creating a numeric variable issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a new variable as the mean of another numeric var present in my database `(mark1 type = float)`.
Unfortunately, the result is a new colunm with all `NaN` values.
still can't understand the reanson why.
The code i made is the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("students2.csv")
df.loc[:, 'mean_m1'] = pd.Series(np.mean(df['mark1']).mean(), index= df)
```

this the first few rows after the code:

```
df.head()
   ID  gender  subject  mark1  mark2  mark3       fres  mean_m1
0   1      mm        1   17.0   20.0   15.0        neg      NaN
1   2       f        2   24.0  330.0   23.0        pos      NaN
2   3  FEMale        1   17.0   16.0   24.0          0      NaN
3   4    male        3   27.0   23.0   21.0          1      NaN
4   5       m        2   30.0   22.0   24.0   positive      NaN
```

`None` error messages are printed.
thx so much!

Comment: i have a df that contains: a numeric variable (mark1 - float) and a categorical variable (gender). All i wish to do is to create on the same dataframe a column calculated as the mean(mark1) . would be greater to calculate that mean groupped by gender. thx a lot!

Comment: So, for your example, what do you want as your output? A constant that's equal to the mean of all `mark1`?

Comment: no, i would like to compute the mean(mark1) groupped by gender.

Comment: and in your gender, what is the difference between `m` `mm` and `male`?

Comment: in fres, what is 0,1,neg,pos?? are these the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need `GroupBy` + `transform` with `'mean'`.

For the data you have provided, this is trivially equal to `mark1`. You should probably map your genders to categories, e.g. `M` or `F`, as a preliminary step.

```
df['mean_m1'] = df.groupby('gender')['mark1'].transform('mean')

print(df)

   ID  gender  subject  mark1   mark2  mark3      fres  mean_m1
0   1      mm        1 17.000  20.000 15.000       neg   17.000
1   2       f        2 24.000 330.000 23.000       pos   24.000
2   3  FEMale        1 17.000  16.000 24.000         0   17.000
3   4    male        3 27.000  23.000 21.000         1   27.000
4   5       m        2 30.000  22.000 24.000  positive   30.000
```